# How can I get this rotated anchor to be positioned against right side?

Tags: html, css

What I'm attempting to do is place a slide-out panel jQuery thing to display some ancillary information about a selected recipe on my website.

I used [this example](http://spyrestudios.com/how-to-create-a-sexy-vertical-sliding-panel-using-jquery-and-css3/) as a starting point for the slide-out panel.  But the anchor that triggers the sliding panel takes up more screen real estate than I'd like so I wanted to rotate it 90 degrees and place it against the right side of the page.  I looked at [this site](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation) for an example of how to do the rotation.  Essentially what I end up with is something like this:

```
<a class="trigger" href="#">Nutrition</a>
```

and some css that looks like this:

```
a.trigger{
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 100px; 
    right: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background:#333333;
    border:1px solid #444444;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);   
}
```

And what results is this:

[image]

So, that `right:0` jazz in the CSS doesn't seem to fix things.  It's not against the right side.  It seems like it's offset by the original width, like it is rotated with the lower left-hand corner of the rectangle being the origin.  (This is in IE by the way - and that's generally what we use in-house.)

I didn't see an offset argument or a way to specify where the origin is.  Might be that I've just missed the page in my searching that explains exactly how to do that - if so, I'd be interested in the link to it or if you've got ideas how to solve this, I'd appreciate hearing how to do it or perhaps a different way to accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: How about giving negative value to `right:-somevalue`

Comment: Your padding-right is contributing to the problem, but something else is working against you too. As @Ehtesham mentions, you could do a negative `right`, in which case in IE9 use `-68px`, or `-28px` if you remove the padding-right. However, if you remove the padding-right, it monkeys with the box. http://jsfiddle.net/equHa/ Note, the styles don't seem to translate well to Firefox, in which it looks terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned elements will only work relative to their parent container, make sure that the main container that houses your anchor has a `position:relative;` attribute added to it.